# How to divide each value of 10 rows by the average of the next two rows for each column of data frame?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to divide each of the values for 10 samples/rows by the average of the 2 subsequent rows. For example, in my mock data this would be each of the values in my 1:10 rows, divided by the average of the two following checks, check1_1 and check2_1 and then each of the values of the next rows (13:22) divided by the average of the two following checks, check1_2 and check2_2 and so on.

```
         structure(list(sample_grp = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3", 
       "sample4", "sample5", "sample6", "sample7", "sample8", "sample9", 
       "sample10", "check1_1", "check2_1", "sample11", "sample12", "sample13", 
       "sample14", "sample15", "sample16", "sample17", "sample18", "sample19", 
       "sample20", "check1_2", "check2_2"), col1 = c(0.6578, 0.03456, 
       0.567, 0.001, 0.8796, 0.345, 0.26891, 0.56293, 0.0345, 0.5678, 
       0.98649, 0.9235, 0.5436, 0.1236, 0.00234, 0.546, 0.356, 0.4567, 
       0.4577, 0.4356, 0.4568, 0.2314, 0.457, 0.8769)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

I understand I can use lapply to apply the function to each of the columns of my data frame. However, I am unsure how to initially specify this function of divide each value of the 10 rows by the average of the two rows after this block of 10 (using data.table?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) data.table** Define a vector `g` to split by and then divide the first 10 elements of col1 in each such group by the mean of the 11th and 12th and so on for each successive set of 12 rows.  We have assumed that this is to be applied to all columns except the first.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(DF)
g <- DT[, rep(1:.N, each = 12, length = .N)]
nms <- names(DT)[-1]
divByMean <- function(x) c(x[1:10]/mean(x[11:12]), x[11:12])
DT[, c(nms) := lapply(.SD[, -1], divByMean), by = g]
```

**2) Base R** or just with base R:

```
nr <- nrow(DF)
g <- rep(1:nr, each = 12, length = nr)
divByMean <- function(x) replace(x, 1:10, x[1:10]/mean(x[11:12]))
replace(DF, -1, Map(function(x) ave(x, g, FUN = divByMean), DF[-1]))
```

Comment: thank you for your reply - I wanted to double check I am understanding the code correctly, I have 360 rows altogether (30 groups of 12 with each set of 10 being divided by the average of the 2 immediately after), so defining g will allow for this? I don't need to redefine the divByMean each time i.e  divByMean <- function(x) c(x[13:22]/mean(x(23:24]), x[23:24]), and so on.

Comment: Suppose DF is nr by nc. Then g has length nr and consists of 12 consecutive 1's, followed by 12 consecutive 2's and so on. The whole calculation is done on every column except the first so divByMean is invoked (nc-1) * nr / 12 times.